# Spring boot disable Http11InputBuffer logging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, logging

I want to prevent my app from logging the body of all http request.
So i create a component with

```
CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
filter.setIncludeQueryString(false);
filter.setIncludePayload(false);
```

But setting up

> logging.level.root=DEBUG

to my application.properties seems that Http11InputBuffer still log my request body.
Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the CommonsRequestLoggingFilter does the logging you want to preven.
Anyway, you can set logging level, or disable logging completely, for specific package or class like this:

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  config: classpath:logback-spring.xml
  level:
    root: DEBUG
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer: OFF
```

Comment: Great it works! Is there a documentation about spring properties and loggin where I can learn more?

Comment: [The official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-logging) should bring all the information you need.